sins before puberty
So say someone committed a sin before puberty, and now that they are older my mind continues to remind me of it and it just bothers me so much , does this mean that this person wasn’t forgiven or doesn’t mean something else?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

The actions of children before reaching the age of puberty are not recorded as sins in Islam. This ruling is based on the following authentic hadith:

“The pen has been lifted from three: from the sleeper until he wakes up, from the minor until he grows up, and from the insane until he comes back to his senses or recovers.”
https://sunnah.com/nasai/27/44

Explanation:
The “lifting of the pen” means that actions, whether sinful or obligatory, are not recorded against these three individuals, including minors.
Children are not held accountable for their deeds until they reach the age of puberty, which marks the beginning of their moral and religious responsibilities.
